# Waiting till this animation is finished before repeating on another link

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am having a little trouble with this piece of code

```
    $('.tree-item').hover(function() {

    $('#_'+this.id).fadeIn().delay(500).animate({ left: "0px" }, 200);

},function () {
    $('#_'+this.id).animate({ left: "3000px" }, 200, function(){
        $(this).fadeOut().css('display', 'none').animate({ left: "-3000px" }, 300);
    });
    $(this).stop();    
});
```

I have a tree with links on and this piece of code brings in a cloud with content when the link is hovered over.

I need it to wait until the last link hover actions are complete before starting the current link actions as it can look very messy if the user hovers quickly over the links..

You can view what I mean here http://foc.dev.lemon-fresh.co.uk/#program

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You could also stop queued animation with [.stop(true)](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: I think there is a bigger issue, you can't just wait for the animation to be finished, because you don't know how far it is through the animation, you'll have to solve that first. I'd suggest keeping a track of whether something is open and only begin showing when it has completed closing.

Comment: Hi Will, Could you elaborate for a jQuery noob :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All jQuery animation functions have a `complete` callback method which will be executed when the animation is complete.

> .animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete] )

ref: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$(this).animate({}, 200, null, function() {
    //do this when ready...
});
```